# Decreasing accelerometer's sensitivity

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, accelerometer, core-motion

I am making a game which have a square that moves from left to right, and at first I was using `applyForce` to do so, but I didn't like the results because it was not sensitive enough. Then I changed to `velocity`:

```
func motionSensorUpdate(currentTime: CFTimeInterval){

    let square = childNodeWithName(ksquarename) as! SKSpriteNode

    updateSquare(currentTime, Square: square)

    if let data = motionManager.accelerometerData {

        if CGFloat(data.acceleration.x) > 0.2 {
            square.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(200, -200)
        } else if CGFloat(data.acceleration.x) < 0.2 {
            square.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(-200, -200)
        }
    }
}
```

The problem now is that it's too sensitive. So, if I'm not moving the cellphone it would still move the object. How do I fix it without moving back to `applyforce`?

Comment: I'm not sure using `velocity` is appropriate here - are you seeing results where the node is not moving at all, and then suddenly moving once you tilt your phone past a threshold? You could have just increased the strength of the the force you were applying...

Comment: When I was applying force, it didn't respond quickly. For example, if I was tilting to the left, and then I wanted to quickly go to the right the force applied would imitate a real object, and that's not what I want. Using velocity it responds quickly, but it's so sensitive that even if I'm stopped the square moves to the left or to the right, frequently zigzagging which feels weird.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
let multiplier = 200.0
let x = data.acceleration.x

if x > 0.2 {
    square.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: x * multiplier, dy: -200)
} else if x < 0.2 {
    square.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVector(dx: x * multiplier, dy: -200)
}
```

The above will vary the speed of the node depending on how much the device is tiled; just change `multiplier` to change the sensitivity.

Comment: I had to change the code because it wouldn't take care of Int and Double together. But now for some reason CGVectorMake doesn't recognize X as an Int

Comment: let multiplier = 200.0
            let x = data.acceleration.x * multiplier
            
            if x / multiplier > 0.2 {
                square.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(Int(x), Int(-x))
            } else if x / multiplier < 0.2 {
                square.physicsBody!.velocity = CGVectorMake(Int(x), Int(-x))
            }

Comment: Why are you using `Int`? It's a better idea to use `Double` or `CGFloat` because you'll be able to have values of `x` that aren't integers - making the change in velocity of your node smoother. Also, I updated my answer to use `CGVector(dx: x, dy: x)`.

Comment: For the purposes of my game I couldn't use X in DY, but now it works perfectly!!! Thank you so much @ABakerSmith

Comment: Happy to help :) Good luck with your game.